# Why print this value in javascript closure?

Tags: javascript, closures

I know some closure mechanism, but this code confuses me.

I can understand why `num value in message：1` is printed because of `unmount`'s stale closure

but why `num value: 5` is printed instead of `num value: 1`? Isn't `num` also stale in `unmount` closure?

```
const test = () => {
  let num = 0;

  const effect = () => {
    num += 1;
    const message = `num value in message：${num}`;

    return function unmount() {
      console.log(message);
      console.log("num value:", num);
    };
  };

  return effect;
};
const add = test();
const unmount = add();
add();
add();
add();
add();
unmount(); // num value in message：1 ; num value: 5
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-fire-d1gg0?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Isn't num also stale in unmount closure?

No, because only one `num` is ever created, right here:

```
let num = 0;
```

when test runs, and test only runs once.

Any references to `num` will refer to that one variable. When the effect runs, `num += 1;` will increment that one variable.

But if you created a new variable inside effect instead of incrementing the outer one, it would be stale.

```js
const test = () => {
  let num = 0;

  const effect = () => {
    const innerNum = num + 1;
    const message = `num value in message：${innerNum}`;

    return function unmount() {
      console.log(message);
      console.log("num value:", innerNum);
    };
  };

  return effect;
};
const add = test();
const unmount = add();
add();
add();
add();
add();
unmount(); // num value in message：1 ; num value: 5
```

The message is "stale" because that string that's created and used is created before the `num` has finished being incremented by all the add calls. If you got unmount from the last add, it wouldn't be stale.

```js
const test = () => {
  let num = 0;

  const effect = () => {
    num += 1;
    const message = `num value in message：${num}`;

    return function unmount() {
      console.log(message);
      console.log("num value:", num);
    };
  };

  return effect;
};
const add = test();
add();
add();
add();
add();
const unmount = add();
unmount();
```